# How Can I debug scrapy spiders in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, scrapy, spyder

I have a spider as follows:

```
class EcsWiki5(CrawlSpider):
    name='ecs_wiki5'
    allowed_domains = ["intel.com"]

    def __init__(self, domain='', keyword='', term='', *args, **kwargs):
        super(CrawlSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.domain=domain
        if domain == 'some string':
            self.url1='some URL'
        self.keyword=keyword
        self.term=term
        
    
    def start_requests(self):
                
        request = Request.from_curl(curl_string1, callback = self.parse)
        yield request
    
    def parse(self,response):
        name = []
        hyperlink = []
        searchkey=self.keyword
        title=response.xpath("//head/title/text()").extract()
        wikicontent=response.xpath("//div[@class='wiki-content']")
        for sel in wikicontent.xpath("//tbody/tr/th/a"):
            print(sel.xpath("text()").extract())
            name.append(str(sel.xpath("text()").extract()))
            print(sel.xpath("@href").extract())
            hyperlink.append(str(sel.xpath("@href").extract()))
        for sel in wikicontent.xpath("//tbody/tr/th/p/a"):
            print(sel.xpath("text()").extract())
            name.append(str(sel.xpath("text()").extract()))
            print(sel.xpath("@href").extract())
            hyperlink.append(str(sel.xpath("@href").extract()))
        for sel in wikicontent.xpath("//tbody/tr/th/p/strong/a"):
            print(sel.xpath("text()").extract())
            name.append(str(sel.xpath("text()").extract()))
            print(sel.xpath("@href").extract())
            hyperlink.append(str(sel.xpath("@href").extract()))
        for sel in wikicontent.xpath("//tbody/tr/td/a"):
            print(sel.xpath("text()").extract())
            name.append(str(sel.xpath("text()").extract()))
            print(sel.xpath("@href").extract())
            hyperlink.append(str(sel.xpath("@href").extract()))
        for sel in wikicontent.xpath("//tbody/tr/td/p/a"):
            print(sel.xpath("text()").extract())
            name.append(str(sel.xpath("text()").extract()))
            print(sel.xpath("@href").extract())
            hyperlink.append(str(sel.xpath("@href").extract()))
        counter = -1
        for n in name:
            counter = counter + 1
            if name[counter]=="['"+searchkey+"']":
                link=hyperlink[counter]
                link = link.replace("[","")
                link = link.replace("'","")
                link = link.replace("]","")
                print(link)
                request = Request.from_curl(curl_string2, callback = self.parse_leaves)
                yield request
...
```

I am using spyder IDE.
Now to debug every time I have to check the output in notepad and figure out what went wrong. I want to use the debugging features like breakpoints and step in spyder. I am unable to start the spider from the ipython console in spyder. I have to start the spider from Anaconda prompt and it doesn't stop until the entire code gets executed. What do I do to debug my spider? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A7bBMcVZWSM) for that. It's the best resource we have about our debugger at the moment. A shorter video tutorial and written documentation will come in the next months.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how expierenced you are in Spyder IDE. Maybe you should go through this
https://wiki.math.ntnu.no/anaconda/debugging . As far i know there is a toolbar in Spyder which is named "Debug". There you can set Breaktpoints and so on.
I hope this is what you searched for..

Comment: I can add breakpoints. But the execution does not stop at the breakpoints because there is no way I can run the spider from inside the spyder IDE

Comment: So another thing i sometimes do (i know its not that popular) when i don't have an IDE installed when programming embedded systems: inserting a "print('debug')" command in the line you would add the breakpoint. You can add several of this lines and numerate them, so you can do something similar to the breakpoints...